# A standard way of installing Poetry projects globally

Tags: python, python-poetry

I often want to use my own personal Python projects for daily use. In golang, I can just run `go install project.go` and the compiled binary is sent to `~/go/bin` (which is in my PATH). Now I can run my program anywhere globally in my system. Is there an equivalent for this in Python and Poetry?

I can probably workaround this by writing a script that runs something along the lines of `poetry run $project` and put that script in one of my PATHs. But what I want to know is if there is a *standard* way of doing this in Python and Poetry.

What I want is something along the lines of `pip install program` but for my own projects.

Right now, I need to `cd` into my project folder and run `poetry run $project` every time I want to run my program, which is really cumbersome.

Comment: Are you looking for something like pipx? https://pypa.github.io/pipx/

Comment: "What I want is something along the lines of ``pip install program`` but for my own projects." Why not use ``pip install my_own_project``, then?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Huh, didn't know why I didn't think of trying just that. `pip install path/to/project` just works, thanks!

Comment: You can install your package via [setuptools](https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html)

Answer (score 7):

Pip works with poetry projects.

Try:

```sh
pip install /path/to/your/project
```

Comment: Dunno why this answer is getting hated on. It's the same solution as I now see was implicitly accepted in the comments.

Comment: I use this method and it's fine. I think the fact the question explicitly states "I want pip install x, but for my own projects" means that this is absolutely the correct answer given the scope of the question.